# When to use Hoare’s vs Lomuto's scheme in Quick Sort? - Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm learning about sorting algorithms at school right now and had to code out both Lomuto and Hoare for Quick Sort.

From my understanding, Hoare's is more efficient since it moves from both ends into the middle, swapping at a higher rate. I've haven't gotten to the point where I would implement them into my projects yet.... What would be some cases that you would use Lomuto vs Hoare?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11458/quicksort-partitioning-hoare-vs-lomuto/11550#11550

Comment: For Hoare scheme, if array is already sorted and either first or last element is chosen as pivot, it calls itself n-1 times, with stack space complexity O(n). Using the middle element as pivot fixes this issue for already sorted data or reverse sorted data. Most library implementations of quicksort use a hybrid variation such as [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) to avoid worst case scenarios.